# Error when pushing Ruby gem (credentials "not found")

Tags: ruby, deployment, rubygems

When running gem push "example.gem", I get asked to put my GitHub username and password, instead of rubygems.org.
I've put my credentials for BOTH and I know they are correct, but I keep on getting them rejected with a "Not Found" response.
Anyone knows the solution? Here's part of my gemspec file if that helps:

```
Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  spec.name          = "gemname"
  spec.version       = GEMNAME::VERSION
  spec.authors       = ["author"]
  spec.email         = ["author@gmail.com"]

  spec.summary       = "Example Gem"
  spec.description   = "Example Gem"
  spec.homepage      = "http://rubygems.org/gems/examplegem"
  spec.license       = "MIT"
  spec.required_ruby_version = Gem::Requirement.new(">= 2.4.0")

  spec.metadata["allowed_push_host"] = "https://rubygems.org/profiles/username"

  spec.metadata["homepage_uri"] = spec.homepage
  spec.metadata["source_code_uri"] = "https://rubygems.org/profiles/username"
```

Comment: When you run `gem push example...` then that gem in that specific version will be pushed to Rubygems. Why do you think it is asking you for your GitHub credentials? Please share the exact command you run and copy and paste the full output of that command.

Comment: It's the first version, therefore it's displayed as "gemname-0.1.0.gem".
Then I run "gem push gemname-0.1.0.gem". That's then it asks for my GitHub credentials. I do it and it returns "Not Found".

Comment: Are you sure it's asking for GitHub and not RubyGems credentials? `gem push` publishes a gem to RubyGems, so you need to have registered with it first. Posting the command/output would help use help you.

Comment: @rmlockerd Yes, and that's what I'm finding weird. It's supposed to ask for RubyGems credentials instead of GitHub. The problem is that I haven't set it to GitHub, and I can't figure out how to change the push path to RG. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Try running `gem environment` and check what it thinks the remote source(s) is/are. You might check to see if somehow you've got a `gemrc` file in either your home or working directory and check to see if you have `RUBYGEMS_HOST ` set in your environment to something weird.

Comment: @rmlockerd Did that and had rubygems.org as my default path. Since then, I've been getting closer to the solution, after commenting out some lines in gemspec and updating rubygems. The problem is different now. After rebuilding and trying to push the gem, it returns "Access Denied. Please sign up for an account at https://rubygems.org", while I obviously already have an account there and I made sure I'm logged in. Since the current issue is different from the first one, I wonder if I should continue this thread or open a new one.